# TikZ cover underlying shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to hide parts if the underlying shape. In this case, I would like to hide the parts of the blue object which are covered by the red one.

[image]

```
\begin{scope}[rotate=45]
  \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue!30] (0.5,-1.25) circle[x radius=0.75cm, y radius=0.5cm];
  \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red!30] (0,0) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=0.5cm] -- +(0,-1) -- +(-1,-1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
```

What is the usual way of doing this?
I tried using filling the red one white. Is `clip` needed here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind to loose the transparency, you can fill the upper shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=45]
  \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue!30] (0.5,-1.25) circle[x radius=0.75cm, y radius=0.5cm];
  \draw[preaction={fill=white}, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red!30] (0,0) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=0.5cm] -- +(0,-1) -- +(-1,-1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is a tongue? :-)

Comment: Maybe one part of a chair... ;-) :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano It's suposed to be a red electric guitar. I need other hats ;-)

Comment: What can I do to get you more hats?

Comment: @Sebastiano No idea! Don't worry. The problem is that until now I only have two hats, both red, and they look strange over my red icon.